# Is there any free code signing tools

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development

I have been making a program for some time now that makes your computer run faster. I have compiled it but it is coming up as a virus because it removes file, changes settings, modifies registry and some other things too. I know it isn't harmful but it isn't trusted by antivirus software. The program was made using VBScript, Batch, html and power-shell.

I found out my only way to solve this is to buy a digital certificate and these cost £100 plus and for small protects this is a real show stopper. I only have around £50 to launch it and than needs to go on thing like web-hosting and advertising.

So does any one know how I could get a digital certificate for free or one for under £20. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We don't give website recommendations here - see [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/219/46) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is not the tool (which is most likely some VB Script in your case) which is gratis or not.

The problem is that certificates for such a task are not gratis, intentionally.

Leaving aside all the possible attacks on the certification process the Idea is the following:

If a software wants to change important settings it should be clear who owns the software.
As the average user can't prove that a software is from a given author he trusts a third party (the certificate authority) that they prove it for them.
This Certificate Authority proves this by requiring you to pay for such a certificate so they have at least some bank transfer document, E-Mail or something the like that is secure enough for them.
The more checks they do, the more expensive the certificate gets (other factors come into play as well).

So, the signing tool is gratis, the certificate is not.

Comment: Arguably the bigger hurdle is that as an individual you can only ever obtain an ordinary class 3 certificate, but not an EV one. You need a registered business for that. I don't think there is a _need_ for this to cost money. The argument was similarly put forward in case of SSL/TLS certificates and Let's Encrypt is the best proof that there is no inherent need for this to cost money. Besides, leaked certificates along with their private key and fraudulent business really chip away from the argument that a consumer gains anything by trusting a CA to verify developer identity.